# What is better: 5 query to mysql or 5 loops in the single result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of 500 records. I have to take 5 records from there and I cannot use "where" clause for all 5 of them: the second select depends on the result of the first etc.

I have 3 ways:
1. One query `"Select * FROM .."`, and then 5 loops:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
if($row['id'] == $id){
// ...
break;
}
```

2. I can perform 5 query `"SELECT * FROM .. WHERE id=id`.
3. I don't know if it's possible: can I search in the result of `mysql_query($query)` without making a loop? Something like:

`$res=mysql_query($query);
$row = $res[$id];`

Comment: you may try to use LIMIT 5

Comment: For a start, mysql is deprecated, use mysqli. Secondly, under what criteria are you selecting your records, it's difficult to follow the details of your problem.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins PHP's mysql API is deprecated. MySQL's doing just fine ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry - indeed, thank you for picking up on my ambiguity :-)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely one query with five IDs using `IN`.

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE id IN (1, 2, 4, 13, 21)
```

Comment: I know, but I cannot use it in my case.. When I am asking for the first row, I don't know which one I'll need then...

Comment: Is there something like id and parent_id where parent_id of one record = id of the second one? Or why dont you know all five `$id`s? How 2nd depends on 1st, 3rd on 2nd, etc.?

Comment: No, it's like I have to take 5 photos from db, and there is a script that analyse the name and decide which one I need.. Now I am trying to use mysqli, so I'll send 5 queries each time...